# Porque no quiere insertar los datos?

Tags: php, sql, poo

Trato de insertar los datos con esta consulta usando la interpolacion de variables con POO y me devuelve false

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES( '{$this->getDoc_ident()}', '{$this->getNombre()}' , '{$this->getApellidos()}', '{$this->getFecha_nac()}' ,'{$this->getCorreo()}', '{$this->getSexo()}' ,'{$this->getPais()}' ,'user' ,'{$this->getPass()}');";

        $save = $this->db->query($sql);


        $result = false;
        if ($save) {
            $result = true;
        }
```

Comment: Intenta capturar el error que te retorna la ejecucción del sql. Si puedes poner también la estructura de la tabla.

Comment: mete la llamada de la consulta en un bloque try/catch, y muestra el error que te da cuando salta la exception correspondiente